# How to access same TableViewController from all rows of the previous TableViewController but with independent data?

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

I've a DateViewController, that has 10 rows. Each row represents a single Date of the day.

When I click on the first row of the DateViewController, I'm brought to the  AnimalTableViewController that contains 5 rows as follow:

1. **Cat** --- age = 0 --- height = 0 --- weight = 0
2. **Lion** --- age = 0 --- height = 0 --- weight = 0
3. **Dog** --- age = 0 --- height = 0 --- weight = 0
4. **Crow** --- age = 0 --- height = 0 --- weight = 0
5. **Ant** --- age = 0 --- height = 0 --- weight = 0

**Note:** age, height and weight are the buttons in each row of the AnimalViewController. When I click on these buttons the values of the corresponding variables are changed.
Let after some random clicks on the buttons, the new values stored are as follow:

1. **Cat** --- age = 1 --- height = 0 --- weight = 0
2. **Lion** --- age = 0 --- height = 3 --- weight = 0
3. **Dog** --- age = 0 --- height = 0 --- weight = 2
4. **Crow** --- age = 0 --- height = 5 --- weight = 0
5. **Ant** --- age = 0 --- height = 1 --- weight = 0

Question:
I want to load the same AnimalViewController from all other rows of the DateViewController BUT with the default variables' values.

1. **Cat** --- age = 0 --- height = 0 --- weight = 0
2. **Lion** --- age = 0 --- height = 0 --- weight = 0
3. **Dog** --- age = 0 --- height = 0 --- weight = 0
4. **Crow** --- age = 0 --- height = 0 --- weight = 0
5. **Ant** --- age = 0 --- height = 0 --- weight = 0

And if the changes are made in the AnimalViewController coming from the second row of DateViewController, these should not affect the values of the AnimalViewController coming from the first row of the DateViewController.

In short, all rows of the DateViewController should bring up AnimalViewController, but all of these resultant AnimalViewController's variables should be independent of each other.

What is the best method (code) implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a set of Animal objects for each row in your DateViewController.  Pass the correct set to the AnimalViewController depending on which date row is selected.

Comment: I would suggest a dictionary, keyed by date, with each entry in the dictionary being an array of Animals